# Problems Linking to libcuda.so

Tags: gcc, linker, cuda, g++, shared-libraries

I am stumped by what seems to be a problem that should be easy to diagnose and fix. I have a C++ source file that makes use of the CUDA Driver API. When I compile it using `nvcc`, the executable is produced and works without problems. However, when I try to compile it using `g++`, the linker complains about undefined references to symbols that are in `/usr/lib/libcuda.so`:

```
undefined reference to cuDeviceGet'
... undefined reference tocuDeviceComputeCapability'
... undefined reference to cuDeviceGetName'
... undefined reference tocuDeviceTotalMem_v2'
... undefined reference to cuDeviceGetAttribute'
... undefined reference tocuDeviceGetAttribute'
... undefined reference to cuDeviceGetAttribute'
... undefined reference tocuDeviceGetAttribute'
```

I tried to ensure that `/usr/lib` is included in the library path (by supplying the flags `-L/usr/lib`, `-lcuda`, and adding `/usr/lib` to `$LIBRARY_PATH`). However, the problem still persists. I am sure that `/usr/lib/libcuda.so` contains the symbols that the linker is complaining about:

```
$ nm -D /usr/lib/libcuda.so | grep cuDeviceGet
00000000000be410 T cuDeviceGet
00000000000bf120 T cuDeviceGetAttribute
00000000000d2e10 T cuDeviceGetByPCIBusId
00000000000be200 T cuDeviceGetCount
00000000000bdfa0 T cuDeviceGetName
00000000000d2bb0 T cuDeviceGetPCIBusId
00000000000bf380 T cuDeviceGetProperties
```

I find it strange that `nvcc` successfully compiles the file, but `g++` does not. Do you have any idea as to how I can fix this problem?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Make sure you also have the `-lcuda` compiler flag to actually include the library, and that the libcuda.so you are trying to link against is for the same platform (32/64 bit). There is often a /usr/lib64 on 64 bit versions

Comment: I also included this flag -- I should have mentioned this, but I updated the question accordingly.

Comment: Something I didn't understand as a new CUDA user... this is not the same as the cuda runtime (cudart) library that comes with the CUDA Toolkit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, the reason I was not able to compile the file was because the `-lcuda` flag has to come **after** the filename. Otherwise, it won't work... a large, prominent warning with the compiler telling me this information would have been much appreciated. Well, that was a waste of two hours.

Comment: The worst part is I have had this problem in the past, and should have realised

Comment: Haha it's fine, it's a lesson I'm definitely not going to forget.

Comment: Could be worse. I got stuck on a bug for a week and eventually found the answer on SO. (Mine was the accepted answer - apparently I had slept since then.)