# Opencv Building Error

Tags: ubuntu, opencv, build, makefile, build-process

Im trying to setup Opencv with cuda=on on ubuntu 12.04. I did cmake Opencv with all settings which I want without any problem and my Cuda toolkit is working smooth. However, when I come make step of Opencv machines has given error. While make I got error

**`Linking CXX executable ../../bin/opencv_perf_core`**

My guake terminal view is below

```
brkn@brknPC:~/Source/OpenCV-2.4.2/release$ make
[  4%] Built target opencv_core
[  5%] Built target opencv_ts
[ 11%] Built target opencv_imgproc
[ 14%] Built target opencv_highgui
Linking CXX executable ../../bin/opencv_perf_core
../../lib/libopencv_core.so.2.4.2: error: undefined reference to 'cuDeviceGetAttribute'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [bin/opencv_perf_core] Error 1
make[1]: *** [modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_perf_core.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
brkn@brknPC:~/Source/OpenCV-2.4.2/release$
```

I stuck in here and I cannot throw it off do you have any suggestion?

Comment: have you checked [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10402245/problems-linking-to-libcuda-so) ?

Comment: I have checked. Why you think problem you link related with mine.

Comment: because your error is an undefined reference to cuda library. what is the output of make VERBOSE=1 ? Use pastebin or ideone.com and put the link

Answer (score -1):

i also encounter this problem. here's what i tried.

1. link the libcuda to /usr/lib depend on what driver you use. this version used nvidia-current-updates

   su -c 'ln -s /usr/lib/nvidia-current-updates/libcuda.so /usr/lib/libcuda.so && ln -s /usr/lib/nvidia-current-updates/libcuda.so.1 /usr/lib/libcuda.so.1'
2. run 'cmake' again
3. then continue 'make'

Comment: Does not work. Could  you modify your answer